# How do I get an "animation" to play?

Tags: animation

This assumes that "animation" means what I think it does. "a way of making a movie by using a series of drawings, computer graphics, or photographs of objects (such as puppets or models) that are slightly different from one another and that when viewed quickly one after another create the appearance of movement" http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/animation

What I did: In Wolfram Programming Cloud, entered the docs' example

```
Animate[Plot[Sin[x + a], {x, 0, 10}], {a, 0, 5},AnimationRunning -> False]
```

What I got:
[image]

Static.

What I want: That, animated. Which is what I expect given https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Animate.html  "Animate[expr,{u,umin,umax}] generates an animation of expr in which u varies continuously from umin to umax".

Likewise the page from the link from CloudDeploy[%] does not animate.

Comment: Dont have access to WPC to check, but isn't there a play button you can press to start the animation? Does anything change on WPC if you remove the `AnimationRunning -> False` option?

Comment: As we have told you in other questions, WPC is a beta product and only supports a subset of what's available in *Mathematica*. The documentation you refer to is for Mathematica if it doesn't say anything else (as it does for some functions.)

Comment: I don't claim it is off topic but till the valid documentation is released this question requires WRI support to be answer.

Comment: I would email this inconsistency about the documentation (i.e. there is no warning that this doesn't work in the Cloud) to support@wolfram.com.

Comment: Probably during the private beta, I saw a list of interface elements that were not implemented in WPC or WO. Can't find it anywhere at the moment, but some limitations were pretty intuitive (like not being able to use local gamepads as controllers) given the implementation concept (client/server with considerable delays won't allow for rapid feedback situations needed for many GUI elements).

Comment: This is not yet implemented. The absence of an error message is a bug; it should have been "Animate::cloudf: Animator is not currently supported in the Wolfram Cloud."

Comment: @Pickett  "The documentation you refer to is for Mathematica if it doesn't say anything else (as it does for some functions.)" The documentation to which I referred to is that presented in the WPC IDE. Whilst Wolfram presents it as the documentation for WPC, I'll take it as the (admittedly imperfect) documentation for WPC.

Comment: @Kuba "I don't claim it is off topic" May I ask then why you have lent you name to the putting of this on hold as off-topic?

Comment: @MarcoB, no there is no Play button. No, there is no change on removing AnimationRunning -> False. Thanks anyway for the suggestions.

Comment: @chuy, Thanks chuy but my issue is not with the documentation, but with the program. I can see no good reason animation doesn't work in WPC. I use other web apps in which it does.

Comment: @Sjoerd, "some limitations were pretty intuitive (like not being able to use local gamepads as controllers)" Nothing intuitive about that. WL gamepad is documented to operate sliders and buttons. and local gamepad should work there just as does local mouse.

Comment: @ilian "This is not yet implemented" Source, please?

Comment: I would say the source is [@ilian](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/145/ilian).

Comment: @ChrisJJ You are of course welcome to edit the question to something that you feel you can put your name on, I don't think putting in a paragraph disavowing the question is a good idea. The *Mathematica* reference is meant to make it easier to understand what you are asking. Most of what I edited was to remove needless definitions as I recall; we already know what an animation is for example, you don't have to quote a dictionary :)

Comment: @ChrisJJ What I mean is - "it's fine for me if WPC, Cloud, etc questions are asked here. but till the valid documentation is released the only nonspeculative answer me be given by WRI employees, who don't have a duty to monitor SE so better ask directly.

Comment: @chrisjj, "local game pad should work there just as does the local mouse" That's easier said than done. Given that the whole interface runs in JavaScript within the confines of a browser it just hasn't access to the same resources as a native program would have. There are [some developments](http://www.gamepadjs.com) in this area, but they all require versions of browsers that are not in use by the general public.

Comment: @Picket " You are of course welcome to edit the question to something that you feel you can put your name on" Evidently not. I removed the material false attributed to me, and yet my edits were reverted.

Comment: @Kuba "till the valid documentation is released the only nonspeculative answer me be given by WRI employees" I think you're completely mistaken. Any code that solves the problem is a valid answer. Whether that accords with the docs is immaterial.

Comment: @Sjoerd "That's easier said than done. " a) Like much of WL. b) That doesn't make the failure 'intuitive' as you suggest.  "the whole interface runs in JavaScript" The user should not need to know or care how it is implemented.

Answer (score 13):

As ilian said in [a comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89867/#comment245707_89867):

> This is not yet implemented. The absence of an error message is a bug; it should have been "Animate::cloudf: Animator is not currently supported in the Wolfram Cloud."

Comment: Perhaps you should have left this in its comment. It is not an answer to either the original or current version of the question.

Comment: Dear @ChrisJJ, yes, this is an answer. As noted in the comment and in the post above, it is not currently possible to do this in Wolfram Cloud yet. That is the answer - the feature is not implemented in WPC, so it can't (yet) be done.